# bad reloc address 0x0 when compiling hsdis (Java HotSpot disassembler plugin) on cygwin

Tags: java, c, compilation, cygwin, jvm-hotspot

I'm trying to compile the `hsdis-amd64.dll` library that the JVM needs to disassemble JIT compiled code.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341083/how-to-use-xxunlockdiagnosticvmoptions-xxcompilecommand-print-option-with-j) accepted answer.

- I installed cygwin
- downloaded [openjdk-7u40-fcs-src-b43-26_aug_2013.zip](http://www.java.net/download/openjdk/jdk7u40/promoted/b43/openjdk-7u40-fcs-src-b43-26_aug_2013.zip)
- and downloaded [binutils-2.24.tar.gz](http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.24.tar.gz)

I created a folder structure like this:

```
+
+- hsdis             // unzipped dir hotspot/src/share/tools/hsdis of openjdk zip
+- binutils-2.24     // unzipped binutils-2.24.tar.gz
```

First I tried to just compile it using:

```
$ make OS=Linux MINGW=x86_64-w64-mingw32 BINUTILS=../binutils-2.24
```

but it failed with

```
/Linux-amd64/opcodes/libopcodes.a build/Linux-amd64/libiberty/libiberty.a
hsdis.c:32:20: fatal error: sysdep.h: No such file or directory
#include <sysdep.h>
                ^
compilation terminated.
```

So I applied the patch provided in [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341083/how-to-use-xxunlockdiagnosticvmoptions-xxcompilecommand-print-option-with-j) and tried again.

The compilation failed again

```
In file included from hsdis.c:34:0:
build/Linux-amd64/bfd/bfd.h:35:2: error: #error config.h must be included before this header
#error config.h must be included before this header
^
```

I followed the proposal of the compiler and added `config.h` just before the `errno.h` include.

Then the error is

```
e -I../binutils-2.24/bfd -Ibuild/Linux-amd64/bfd -DLIBARCH_amd64 -DLIBARCH=\"amd64\" -DLIB_EXT=\".dll\" -O hsdis.c -shared build/Linux-amd64/bfd/libbfd.a build/Linux-amd64/opcodes/libopcodes.a build/Linux-amd64/libiberty/libiberty.a
build/Linux-amd64/bfd/libbfd.a(compress.o):compress.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `compressBound'
build/Linux-amd64/bfd/libbfd.a(compress.o):compress.c:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `compress'
build/Linux-amd64/bfd/libbfd.a(compress.o):compress.c:(.text+0x28a): undefined reference to `inflateInit_'
build/Linux-amd64/bfd/libbfd.a(compress.o):compress.c:(.text+0x2c7): undefined reference to `inflate'
build/Linux-amd64/bfd/libbfd.a(compress.o):compress.c:(.text+0x2d6): undefined reference to `inflateReset'
build/Linux-amd64/bfd/libbfd.a(compress.o):compress.c:(.text+0x2f1): undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: build/Linux-amd64/bfd/libbfd.a(compress.o): bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.pdata'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I know that it is a linker problem. For me it seems that it is trying to link against a wrong version, but I might be wrong.

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem or can tell me how to compile the hsdis (HotSpot disassembler plugin)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is need to add linking against zlib (Be sure that you install package mingw64-x86_64-zlib in cygwin).
[image: correct zlib package for x86_64]

Then open Makefile in editor, find rule:

```
$(TARGET): $(SOURCE) $(LIBS) $(LIBRARIES) $(TARGET_DIR)
    $(CC) $(OUTFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCE) $(DLDFLAGS) $(LIBRARIES)
```

Add "-static -lz" to second line to make that:

```
$(TARGET): $(SOURCE) $(LIBS) $(LIBRARIES) $(TARGET_DIR)
    $(CC) $(OUTFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCE) $(DLDFLAGS) $(LIBRARIES) -static -lz
```

Comment: You need to install package mingw64-x86_64-zlib in cygwin.

Comment: You need to install mingw64-x86_64-zlib (you mismatch it with zlib-devel on your screenshot)

Comment: Check for "ls /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/libz.*" in cygwin console. There (if zlib for Win64 toolchain correctly installed) must be two files: libz.a and libz.dll.a

Comment: Thanks, now it compiles perfectly after I did a `make clean`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem could be solved following Marat Buharov's answer.

Nevertheless here are some links where you can find a pre-comiled hsdis plugin:

- http://lafo.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/hsdis/
- https://kenai.com/projects/base-hsdis/downloads
- http://classparser.blogspot.de/2010/03/hsdis-i386dll.html

I tried http://lafo.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/hsdis/intel/hsdis-amd64.dll with jdk1.7.0_02 and it worked.