# Near empty Java For-Loop acts strange

Tags: java, debugging, loops, jvm, nested-loops

This code acts as expected printing "Average Number of Runs: 0.99864197"

```
import java.util.Random;

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int min = -30;
        int max = 1;
        test(min, max);
    }
    static void test(int min, int max){
        int count = 0;
        Random rand = new Random(0);
        for(int j = 0; j < 2097152; j++){
            int number = min + rand.nextInt(max-min+1);
            for(int i = 0; i < number; ++i) {
                System.out.print("");
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Average Number of Runs: " + count/65536F);

    }
}
```

This code that should print the same exact number, but instead it prints a random negative number.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int min = -30;
        int max = 1;
        test(min, max);
    }
    static void test(int min, int max){
        int count = 0;
        Random rand = new Random(0);
        for(int j = 0; j < 2097152; j++){
            int number = min + rand.nextInt(max-min+1);
            for(int i = 0; i < number; ++i) {
                //System.out.print("");
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Average Number of Runs: " + count/65536F);

    }
}
```

Is there some optimization that happens in java for loops?

Notes:

1. I'm using jdk1.6.0_45.
2. In normal usage the new Random would have a better seed.
3. min and max should be able to be any number.

Comment: I seem to remember that this is a duplicate, but I suspect I'll have trouble finding it. I *think* it's a JIT bug in 1.6 which was fixed in Java 7. Can you try on Java 7?

Comment: @JonSkeet I just tried this in Java 7, and this worked perfectly.

Comment: Running the code on jre 7u25 does seem to fix the issue, so it does seem to be a bug in Java 6.  That kind of sucks since a quite a handful of people in the minecraft community, seem to not know how to update and this code is part of a Game-Modification I've been working on... Also @Jon Skeet can you post an Answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: @ZaideChris: Will do, although I'm not sure it's worth much as it is...

Comment: Both code versions work perfectly on java 1.6.0_26.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this to be a bug in the JIT handling of very tight loops in some versions of Java 6. It *may* be either [bug 6196102](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6196102) or bug [6357124](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6357214).

Updating to Java 7 should work, although I appreciate that doesn't help much in your situation. You may find that adding a "looks like it isn't a no-op, but does something you don't care about" method call within your loop fixes the problem too. For example, you could sum all the values of `i`, and print that to some diagnostic log afterwards to be ignored.

Answer (score -1):

It works fine here on `openjdk 1.7.0_25 fedora-2.3.10.4.fc19-x86_64`.
You should update your Java version, or ensure that your problem is actually with the code as stated.